# Does breaking cover/concealment end stealth, post-errata?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, stealth, cover, errata

Once again, stealth is causing problems in Pathfinder, with the stealth errata adding the following line:

> When you start your turn using Stealth, you can leave cover or concealment and remain unobserved as long as you succeed at a Stealth check and end your turn in cover or concealment.

The player believes this means that he can leave cover and attack enemies while remaining stealth.

I believe that from the point you're leaving concealment you're spotted, unless you end your turn in concealment and succeed on a stealth check.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, preferably with as much FAQ, errata and rules rather than logical explanations, since he seems quite resistant to that, but either is fine.

Comment: The [Stealth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/stealth/) skill description's *very next sentence* after the one you quoted says, "Your Stealth immediately ends after you make an attack roll, whether or not the attack is successful (except when sniping as noted below)." That's not an attempt at an (*ahem*) stealth answer, but me wondering what the player thinks that *actually* means.

Comment: I don't really know, I'll try asking him sure. 
The argument is about you're stealthed for the round even if you do not end your turn in cover or concealment and can take the rest of your turn acting as hidden since you started in concealment.

Answer (score 4):

Lead designer [Jason Bulmahn has said](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pt9j&page=2?Stealth-Errata#73):

> The wording was intentionally put together to specify "at the end of your turn". That is the moment when you check your status to see if you can maintain Stealth. This does allow you to move from cover, use Stealth to approach a target, and make a single attack, at which point, Stealth is broken, regardless of the outcome. Now, if you slay that target with one hit, and still could maintain Stealth from all other foes in the area (if say, it is dark and they cannot see you), a GM might reasonably interpret that you could maintain Stealth from other foes, but that requires GM interpretation and is not really the point of this particular situation.